# placing the cursor on a method/var name doesnt show all its appearances in intellij , suddenly

Tags: intellij-idea

In intellij it use to show me all the appearances of any method/variable I place the cursor on , so if i place the cursor on a var/method name "var" it would highlight all the appearances of "var".

How do I set it this behavior back on?

Thanks

Comment: Do you face this problem with all projects even new simple one?

Answer (score 0):

From documentation: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/highlighting-usages.html

## Activating automatic highlighting of usages

1. Open the Settings/Preferences dialog box (File | Settings for Windows and Linux or IntelliJ IDEA | Preferences for macOS), and click General under the Editor node.
2. On the General page that opens, select the Highlight usages of element at caret checkbox in the Highlight on Caret Movement area.

Comment: What happens if you explicitly toggle highlighting by using `Ctrl + Shift + F7`?